# Print the line and a line 10 lines before the match in Linux

Tags: linux, unix

I want to match a string in a file, print the line which matches and the line 10 lines before the match occurs. I am trying using awk, sed and grep, but cant get the right thing. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this command:

```
grep -B 10 PATTERN file.txt
```

Comment: thanks. i used grep -B 10 "abc" test.txt | awk 'NR == 1 { print }END{ print }' to get only the line and the line 10 lines above the match.

Comment: You can also use `grep -B 10 "abc" test.txt | sed -n '1p;$p'`

Answer (score 0):

The `-A` and `-B` options to GNU grep allow you to specify how much context should be displayed after and before the matching line.